# Remove duplicate list item in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I'm retrieving all groups from an axios request at the page load and I store that data inside an empty array inside a reactive object like this,

```
const groupHandler = reactive({
    groups: [],
});
```

And when the user clicked one of his product and click on edit a form will appear like this,

[image]

Here you can see Group 1 has been repeated. And there is another reactive object to store that user's product's group id,

```
const productForm = reactive({
   group: 2,
});
```

So when the user clicks on a product productForm.group will be filled with that product's group id. I want to prevent this been duplicated in my edit product form. I'm using the v-for directive to loop the groups array,

```
<li
    v-for="group in groupHandler.groups"
    :key="group.id"
    :group-id="group.id" >
      {{ group.name }}
</li>
```

So how to prevent this duplicate? In the v-for directive, I could use a condition like if `group.id` is not equal to `productForm.group` print `group.name` But I have no clue to do this. Really appreciate if somebody could help thanks.

Comment: Is the data come duplicated from the API?

Comment: yes from laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `v-for` in the `template` element, and then in the `li` element, you can use `v-if` condition to only render the `group` which doesn't have that `id`

```
<template v-for="group in groupHandler.groups">
<li
    v-if="group.id !== productForm.group"
    :key="group.id"
    :group-id="group.id" >
      {{ group.name }}
</li>
</template>
```

Comment: Bro this is not what I expected. I'm using that same groups[] array in another place to display all groups. So I have to do a condition inside the v-for directive. Thanks.

Comment: So, do you want the duplicated data in the other places? what is the context of the condition you want to add for `v-for`?

Comment: Suppose there is a variable holding an id I just want to use v-for to loop through the groups[] and if there is a record matching with that variable id don't print that print others instead

Comment: any idea bro? Really appreciate your help

Comment: Yes, Got it, I just update the answer, please check.

Comment: This was actually I was looking for bro. Thankyou so much you have helped me before also <3

Comment: You too my bro have a wonderful life <3

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this by using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method in the `v-for` directive itself.

```
v-for="group in groupHandler.groups.filter(({ name }) => !uniqPropValue[name] && (uniqPropValue[name] = true))"
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    uniqPropValue: {},
    groupHandler: {
        groups: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Group 1'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Group 1'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Group 2'
      }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Group 3'
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li
      v-for="group in groupHandler.groups.filter(({ name }) => !uniqPropValue[name] && (uniqPropValue[name] = true))"
      :key="group.id"
      :group-id="group.id">
    {{ group.name }}
  </li>
</div>
```